# jQuery document.getElementById() issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

it seems like jQuery does not recognize my `getElementById()`

There is my .js :

```
$('#start-scraper').click(function() {
var url = document.getElementById("url-value");
getUrlPageContent(url);  
});
```

There is my html code :

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-centre" style="padding-top: 20px;">
            <input id="url-value" type="text" placeholder="https://www.google.fr">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="start-scraper">Scrap !</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

And there is my error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4 
at e (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
at Ab (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
at Ab (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
at Ab (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
at Function.r.param (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
at Function.ajax (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
at getUrlPageContent (scraper.js:7)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (scraper.js:21)
at HTMLButtonElement.handle (jquery.min.js:54)
at HTMLButtonElement.j (jquery.min.js:49)
```

I hope someone will find my problem !

Comment: What's the code of getUrlPageContent?

Comment: what does `getUrlPageContent(url);` do, that's where the issue is - you are passing it a DOM element, did you mean to pass the value of the input instead? From the stack trace it's clear that the first statement in the click handler has executed and the error is inside the function you haven't shown

Comment: You're misreading the error message.

Comment: Also... Why are you storing a dom node in a variable named `url`? just seems a bit mis-leading. just a tiny bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to grab the value for whatever user inputs.  If so, try something like this.

```
var url = document.getElementById("url-value").value;  
getUrlPageContent(url);
```

Keep in mind that you are grabbing whatever is typed into the input.  You will need to add some type of validation as well........

Answer (score 0):

So, I found the problem. I used the DOM element as someone said before, without specify which value I wanted to use.

There is what is working for my part:

```
$('#start-scraper').click(function() {
  var url = document.getElementById('url-value');
  getUrlPageContent(url.value);
});
```

I had to specify what i was searching for inside the DOM element : `getUrlPageContent(url.value)`

Comment: You should accept the answer posted by @Tim B. His solution is exactly the same and he posted it much earlier.